# All my objects have disappeared

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, layers

I don't know where all my objects went. I think I pressed something wrong, but when I press slash or alt+H nothing happens. All of the meshes are grayed out. I think I am in the right layer. Here is a picture.[image: Help]

Comment: What happens if you click the Solid Shading icon (solid grey circle) in the top-right of the toolbar? - You're currently in Material Preview mode although you should still be able to see your objects in that mode. Also try pressing the Home key which should centre your selected object (wall 5) in the viewport. If that doesn't work, share your file at https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like maybe you hid the whole *Collection* (though its hard to tell because I can't see all your objects in the outliner). Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> will not bring back a hidden collection. Scroll up to the top of the outliner and see if the *Collection* is hidden:

[image: Collection]

Comment: Ahhh... okay I can stop typing. Didn't think someone else is awake, but of course I have no idea what time it is for you :D But yep, that's the solution +1

Comment: ...an indicator that the collection is hidden, although not shown in the screenshot, is that the eye symbol on the objects is visible, but it's not as bright as the camera symbol.

Comment: Thnx, It's only 8PM where I am - early for me.

Comment: Oh I see, here it is past 2AM

Comment: Ahh, I see. You're in Germany. I'm in Canada. ;)

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: @Pleasehelp If the answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as accepted [using the third button on the upper left hand corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ZSW.png)? Feel free to use the one on the top too. This helps others know
that the question has been answered sufficiently, and gives the user who answered some more reputation.